# Excluding directories in WebPack doesn't seem to work using path

Tags: webpack, babel-loader

I am using Babel 6.23 and WebPack 5.75 and want to exclude more than one directory.

In webpack.config.js, if I use

exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|)/

then the node_modules directory is indeed excluded, but if I use

exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')

then the node_modules directory is included.

For multiple directories, I try

exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, '/node_modules'), path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts/excludeDirectory')]

but all are included.

Comment: At least one option is that webpack is not in the root folder, the __dirname works from the same directory where your webpack config is. Option to verify - put 
```
console.log('__dirname', __dirname);
```

Comment: I already did that and the directories do map correctly.